# Add AtomicLong to AtomicLong?

Tags: java, math, atomic, long-integer

I'm creating a program to create the Fibonacci sequence, but it keeps messing up because longs can't contain it for very long. I'm trying to switch to AtomicLongs, but I cannot add a atomiclong to an atomiclong, only a regular long? How can I do this, or would it be better to do something more dynamic, like adding two arrays of bytes?

Comment: Why do you need atomic anything here?

Comment: What about a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: Why aren't you using `BigInteger`?

Comment: Aren't AtomicLongs longer than bigintegers? I'll try though, thanks!

Comment: No.  `AtomicLong` is just a Long wrapped by some thread safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AtomicLong` is just a `long` with some extra thread-safe properties; the set of numbers it can store is exactly equal to the set of numbers a `long` can store.

You want a `BigInteger`.